# Phonegap build and media plugin errors

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Greetings.
I am a beginner in javascript. I copied code from a stackoverflow question to make cordova media plugin to work.

This is the  question.
[Phonegap Build with phonegap 3 and media plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096054/phonegap-build-with-phonegap-3-and-media-plugin)

I'm using an online radio streaming url. when i press play button its playing and all other functions are working.

But i encountered some different problems.

1.When i click play button twice, the radio stream is playing twice at the same time..

2.and when i press stop button its stoping the stream, but if i press stop button once again i get an error message.

How to fix this??

My index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>Waves of Power</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="radio.js"></script>
      
      
      
      
      </head>
     
     
     
     
     
     
      <body>
         <div>
          <img class="how" width="800px" height="1280px" src="images/ui.png" />
          </div>
        
        
        
      <div class="cat-wrap">
        <div align="center" class="category" id="blin1">
          <a onClick="pauseAudio();"><img src="images/pause.png" width="90" height="90"  /></a>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category" id="blin2">
            <a onClick="playAudio('http://192.184.9.81:8374/;');"><img src="images/play.png" width="90" height="90" /> </a>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category" id="blin3">
            <a onClick="stopAudio();"><img src="images/stop.png" width="90" height="90" /> </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        
        

      </body>
    </html>
```

My radio.js

```js
// JavaScript Document


        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        //function onDeviceReady() {
        //    playAudio("http://192.184.9.81:8374/;");
        //}

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `if (my_media)`, you are checking if the variable is defined. You also need to check the media playback status. For example, in the `stopAudio()` function, you should check that the audio is actually playing, and in `playAudio()`, check that it isn't currently playing.
You can find how to use the status in the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media).